# Since the fall of Latin as an academic language, has there been a project to revive it?

Tags: academic-latin

> During the Middle Ages and until comparatively recent times, Latin was the language most widely used in the West for scholarly and literary purposes. — [Latin Language](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Latin-language) in the Encyclopaedia Britannica

Since that time, have there been any ambitions to make Latin the primary language of scholars again?
I am interested in all manifestos, published articles, etc. on the subject if followed by concrete actions (translating reference works, adding abstracts in Latin to scientific papers, etc).

Comment: Yes, the effort is called English.

Comment: I translated my PhD's dissertation's abstract to Latin, does it count?

Comment: @Rafael: Excellent, what was it about?

Comment: @Cerberus a traffic flow model. I had to make a lot of technical terms up and it's probably full of mistakes (I didn't really want to spend a lot of time on it).

Comment: @Rafael: I like it!

Answer (score 4):

It is not the same as full revival, but the  International code of botanical nomenclature used to require that *"On or after 1 January 1935 a name of a new taxon (algal and all fossil
taxa excepted) must, in order to be validly published, be accompanied by a
Latin description or diagnosis or by a reference to a previously and effectively published Latin description or diagnosis"* Point 36.1 of the Vienna Code https://www.iapt-taxon.org/historic/2006.htm

As can be seen from the date 1935, this was introduced relatively late. Before it used to be common to just use the language of the rest of the article or book. This requirement was lifted in 2012 and the diagnosis can be either in Latin or in English. Point 39.2 of the current Shenzen Code https://www.iapt-taxon.org/nomen/pages/main/art_39.html

Comment: Such a pity the requirement has been lifted!